# How to remove duplicate rows except one?

Tags: sql, sqlite

On `mytable` no column is primary :

| Name | Company | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | Google | Tester |
| Michael | Google | Tester |
| Michael | Google | Tester |
| Peter | Facebook | Developer |
| Peter | Facebook | Developer |
| Peter | Facebook | Developer |
| Peter | Facebook | Developer |

What I want :

| Name | Company | Position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | Google | Tester |
| Peter | Facebook | Developer |

This does not work :

```
DELETE FROM
   mytable
WHERE
   Name NOT IN (
      SELECT
         MAX(Name)
      FROM
         mytable
      GROUP BY
         Company
   )
;
```

Without new table creation and no CTE, how can I remove duplicate rows except one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can choose to keep the `min` or `max` of `rowid` grouping by the 3 columns shown.

```
delete from myTable
where rowid not in (select min(rowid)
                    from myTable
                    group by name,company,position)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Name,  Company,  Position 
FROM yourTableName
```

In case you want to delete "duplicate" rows you might write this:

yourTableName - should be your real database table

yourColumn  -
 should be your real database column

```
DELETE FROM yourTableName
WHERE yourColumn NOT IN (
    SELECT yourColumn 
    FROM yourTableName
    WHERE yourColumn IS NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Hope this Solution works for you:

```sql
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `mytable` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`Name`, `Company`, `Position`);
```

Comment: wrong language, and it will fail with duplicate data.